# How to add a UILabel into tableview Footer when no new Data Available?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

i want to put a UILabel and UIActivityIndicatorView into UITableView Footer i want when new Data Fetch then UIActivityIndicatorView Start animating and When Not any New Data Avaliable then Lable is Shown Into Table View Footer.

I Write Code for that but it is not Working

```
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
self.newsTable.tableFooterView = spinner;


UILabel *footerlabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
footerlabel.text=@"No New Data Avaliable";
footerlabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
footerlabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
self.newsTable.tableFooterView =footerlabel;

if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    spinner.hidden=FALSE;
    footerlabel.hidden=TRUE;
    NSError* error;
    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        [self.newsTable reloadData];
        NSLog(@"images,%@",self.imageArray);
        [spinner startAnimating];
    }
    self.newsTable.hidden=FALSE;
}
if (responsedata.length == 0)
{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
    footerlabel.hidden=FALSE;
}
}
```

When I add a single View like as Lable/Spinner then it is working but when i add both at same then not any Controller is working.
Please Give me Solution.If It was Possible.

Comment: Add the label and spinner to the view, now add the view to the footerview

Comment: i add that but bro here my each arry are stored in each section then it look like not a good